# Qt Creator keeps old directory after it was renamed; app path is now wrong

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

I use Qt Creator to build a Mac OS program. Recently I renamed the folder containing the project. Unfortunately the program runs incorrectly now. I traced the error to an incorrect application path returned by QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath. The path is incorrect in that it contains the now nonexistent old folder name.

For example:

old project folder: Users/graham/CartoType-3/src/apps/Maps

new project folder (after renaming): Users/graham/CartoType-mainline/src/apps/Maps

I also noticed that when I build the project, I get a message telling me that Qt is creating a stash file in the old folder - which it stubbornly recreates.

I have googled for a long time, and based on what I found, have tried the following:

(i) deleting the .qmake.stash file - no point because Qt Creator calmly recreates it in the wrong place

(ii) deleting the .pro.user file, which contains instances of the incorrect path - that doesn't work because Qt Creator recreates it with the incorrect paths again, then recreates the stash file in the wrong place

(iii) deleting the .qmake.cache file - no point, because there is no cache file after I do a clean, and the problem is still there

So I can only conclude that *somewhere* there is a configuration file containing the old directory name - but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. The erroneous folder names are stored inside Qt Creator and can be edited in the Build Settings pane displayed when you click on the Projects icon in the left sidebar.

Strange how the answer typically becomes clear only *after* one gives up googling and posts a question. However, I hope the information is useful.